# How can I clear random EditTexts?

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I have nine EditTexts that show random numbers.

The method generateSquares set Randomly the texts of EditTexts with numbers from 1 to 9 in an unordered list.

Then I want to clear some EditTexts when the program starts, in the onCreate method.

I want to clear 2,3,4 or 5 of the nine EditTexts randomly.

Once I start the program, I want to clear randomly for example two editTexts.

Those will be
 EditText1+EditText4 or

EditText2+9; or

EditText3+EditText6;

If the algoritm clear 3 EditText those will be

EditText1+EditText4+EditText9 for example.

What I need is after the EditTexts have setted the Text, clear randomly 2, 3, 4 or 5 EditTexts

```
private EditText e1;
private EditText e2;
private EditText e3;
private EditText e4;
private EditText e5;
private EditText e6;
private EditText e7;
private EditText e8;
private EditText e9;

//Set Text of EditTexts randomly (numbers from 1 to 9)

public void generateSquares() {


    // Generates a random array to SetText of EditTexts randomly
    Integer [] shuffleArray = new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    List<Integer> shuffleList = Arrays.asList(shuffleArray);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);
    listaDesordenada.toArray(shuffleList);

    String arrayItem1 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[0]);
    String arrayItem2 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[1]);
    String arrayItem3 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[2]);
    String arrayItem4 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[3]);
    String arrayItem5 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[4]);
    String arrayItem6 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[5]);
    String arrayItem7 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[6]);
    String arrayItem8 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[7]);
    String arrayItem9 = Integer.toString(shuffleArray[8]);


    t1.setText(arrayItem1);
    t2.setText(arrayItem2);
    t3.setText(arrayItem3);
    t4.setText(arrayItem4);
    t5.setText(arrayItem5);
    t6.setText(arrayItem6);
    t7.setText(arrayItem7);
    t8.setText(arrayItem8);
    t9.setText(arrayItem9);

}

 //Clear randomly EditTexts:
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to keep it simple you could generate random **int maxCount** which will tell you how many EditTexts will be cleared. In the next step (loop for example) you will be randomly generating **int index** which will tell you which index (From previously generated array) to clear. You can store the cleared ones in some Array to prevent clearing the same index many times. Is this enough for you?

Comment: Great qki, so I need to store the EditTexts in some Array to delete with the index, now I'll read if I can write an Array of EditTexts, thanks